Expected Value for Complex-Valued Random Variable
This question is part of Exercise 3.14 in the book The Analysis of Time Series: An Introduction with R, 7th Ed., by Chatfield and Xing.
Problem Statement: Suppose $\theta$ is uniformly distributed over the interval $(0,2\pi),$ and consider the complex-valued random variable $Y=g\,e^{i\theta},$ where $g$ is constant. Show that $E(Y)=0.$
My Work So Far: The probability density function for $\theta$ is clearly
$$f_\theta(y)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{1}{2\pi},&y\in(0,2\pi)\\ 0,&\text{elsewhere.}\end{cases}$$
My Question: Is it correct to write down
$$E(Y)=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{g\,e^{i\theta}}{2\pi}\,d\theta?$$
I feel like I might be committing a category error, here, using the density function for $\theta$ to compute the expected value of $Y.$ This integral is zero, but that would be moot if it's the wrong integral!
I thought of trying to compute the probability density function of $Y,$ but nothing came to mind, since $Y$ is complex-valued. The distribution function method, method of transformations, and moment-generating function method all appear to be duds in this case.

It is correct to write this way.  If you are familiar with how characteristic function is formulated and evaluated, I am sure your doubt can be cleared.

I'm not quite following. The problem statement doesn't mentioned the characteristic function. I can see that the characteristic function is like a Fourier Transform of the density function, but that's not quite what I have, here, as far as I can make out.

Write $e^{i\theta}$ as $\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$.

@AdrianKeister What I mean is if you know $X \sim f$, then it is perfectly fine to express $E[e^{iX}]$ as  $\int e^{ix}f(x)dx$.  This is also how a general c.f. $E[e^{itX}]$ is evaluated.

Oh, right. Silly me! The expected value of a function of a random variable is defined that way.

Write $e^{i\theta}$ as $\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta):$
\begin{align*}
E(Y)
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{g\,e^{i\theta}}{2\pi}\,d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{g\,(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))}{2\pi}\,d\theta\\
&=\frac{g}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(\theta)\,d\theta+\frac{g\,i}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(\theta)\,d\theta\\
&=0+0\\
&=0.
\end{align*}

I was aware of how to compute the integral; my question had more to do with whether the integral I was calculating was the correct one or not. Incidentally, you can keep the integral in exponential land and get the same result.

Understood.  The issue of whether the integral you were calculating was correct or not can be answered to an appeal to "The Law of the Unconscious Statistician" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) (of which the name annoys me but it seems to be widely used).  It's not a definition of expectation but rather a very convenient short-cut when certain pretty general conditions hold.
